# VSTO Outlook: Cannot set custom task pane height programmatically

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins

I have a custom task pane which I am trying to set its height programmatically. I have put a breakpoint just at the point where I change its height. From Visual Studio and in debug mode I have observed that after I press F10 key to process the assignment for the custom task pane height, then height is not set to the value I am trying to assign (for example 140), instead its height is changed to a value (80) which I don't know from where it is taken this value.

Why I observe such behavior and it is ignoring the height I am trying to set?

My custom task pane is initialized as below:

```
this.myUserControl = new myUserControl();
this.myCustomTaskPane = Globals.ThisAddIn.CustomTaskPanes.Add(this.myUserControl, Properties.Resources.myText, this.Window);
this.myCustomTaskPane.DockPosition = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoCTPDockPosition.msoCTPDockPositionTop;
this.myCustomTaskPane.DockPositionRestrict = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoCTPDockPositionRestrict.msoCTPDockPositionRestrictNoChange;
this.myCustomTaskPane.Height = 120;
this.myCustomTaskPane.Visible = false;
```

Later when I want to change its height to another value I perform below action:

```
this.myCustomTaskPane.Height = 140;
```

How can I set the height of the custom task pane to be the usercontrol height?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was happening because by default custom task pane has a default minimum height that depends on many factors. In my case was 80 so every time I was changing it to a a smaller value, then Outlook was automatically reasigning the height to the default one (80). Asigning a value greater or equal to 80 was working perfectly.

Comment: Task panes have a min size which couldn't be decreased.

Answer (score 1):

> instead its height is changed to a value (80) which I don't know from where it is taken this value.

This is a min size of the task pane. You can't set lower values. That is by design.